# All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed [EF CORE]

Tags: database, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on my Uni project - .net MVC app. Basic requirement was to create a table of Users containing columns such as id, name, surname etc. which I've done properly. Here is my Model class User.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ProjektPRP.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string? Surname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required]
        public string? Login { get; set; }
        public virtual Role RoleId { get; set; } // used to be "public int RoleId"
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I used `Add-Migration` and User table appeared in database.

Then I had to create another table `Roles` containing roleID and name (admin, moderator, user). I created `Role` class, same as I did before with User.cs and after adding a migration everything was fine.

Then I wanted `User.RoleId` to be a foreign key referencing `Role.Id` (primary key of `Role` table), so I changed `int RoleId` to `virtual Role RoleId` and in `Role.cs` I created a collection of users.

Here is `Role` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjektPRP.Models
{
    public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"a-z")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set; } = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

While trying to migrate once more, the following error occurred:

> The property 'RoleId' cannot be removed from entity type 'ProjektPRP.Models.User (Dictionary<string, object>)' because it is being used in the foreign key {'RoleId'} on 'ProjektPRP.Models.User (Dictionary<string, object>)'. All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed.

I don't really know how can I fix that issue. As I mentioned before - at that phase of writing my project I need two tables:

1. Users with their personal/account data and `RoleID` being a foreign key referring to:
2. Roles with ID and name.

Comment: Don't call navigation property `Id`. Use normal singular name (usually the name of the referenced entity type) and by convention EF Core appends `Id` to it in order to form the FK property/column name. In your case, the property should be `public virtual Role Role { get; set; }` (btw `virtual` keyword is optional, the important is the *type* of the property). You could also keep the explicit FK property `public int RoleId { get; set; }` or remove it and let EF Core use shadow property. Just don't change the type and keep the `Id` name as you did.

Comment: @IvanStoev I changed it so the property is now "public Role Role..." and the error still occurs. I also don't think I understood the second part of your answer. In class User.cs I can use "public int RoleId" and it will "connect" both tables using their common key, in this case Id of the role?

Comment: I guess you'd better take a look at the official EF Core [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#fully-defined-relationships). Replace `Blog` and `Post` from their examples with your `Role` and `User` respectively, and you are done. And yes, `User.RoleId` should be the FK "connecting" it to `Role.Id`.